# How to limit digits when read data from shapefiles with geopandas？

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, io, geopandas

I'm using GIS data which length unit is degree，such as

> (124.32136460574809, 43.595302060916815) # longitude and latitude

You can see the coord has 14 digits behind its decimal dots. This is enough "exact"，however too many digits will bring error and it has suffered me for a long time.

So how to limit digits of coords when read from .shp file like this：

> (124.3213646, 43.59530206) # It has only 7 digits

Thank you for very much.

Comment: Online tools like https://mapshaper.org/ can be used to simplify the geometries. There is an option to specify number of decimal digits of the output. Instruction here:- https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki

Comment: When you create output (OK with GeoJson), use this option:- `-o precision=0.00001` to get 5 digits coordinates.

Comment: I saw this config，thanks.